# Uploading files using tar

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

Can you help me?

I have this piece of code that I'm using on my Ubuntu 16.04 server

```
tar -c /var/www/dxa/backup.zip | ssh <my-server-ip> -p 8000 'tar -xvf - -C /'
```

But everytime I run this command, the terminal ask me user and password. I want make my backup system dynamically, how can I insert at this rule above the user and password to avoid terminal asking?

Thank you.

Comment: authorized_keys

Comment: Hello, I do not understand, can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exchange SSH keys between the machine where this code runs and the machine you intend to connect to.

From the machine where you run the code run (if you haven't previously created a ssh key):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

To create a new ssh key.

Then, run:

```
ssh-copy-id user@remote_machine_ip
```

And provide the user's password once.

This will add the public key of the ssh user from which you intend to run the script from to the authorized_keys of the remote machine user.

Then, the next time you connect, you will not have to supply a password.

Feel free to check [this article](https://www.geek-kb.com/auto-login-linux-machines/), which explains this process.

Comment: Hello, my default port is not 22, so, in this case, should I insert `user@remote_machine_ip:8000`? Because I'm getting: `Name or service not known`

Comment: Also, this server connects to many server, this will work for many servers too?

Comment: No, in your case `ssh-copy-id -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 8000 user@remote_machine_ip`. This can work on all servers you intend to connect to.

Comment: You're welcome friend :)